# Jquery form not submitting after validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

Not sure why, but my form will not submit after I validate it. I am aware I shouldn't use any input fields with the name or ID of "submit" which I am not doing. I am assuming the prevent default method is stopping the submission? How can I validate before submission?

```
<form method="post" id="offersForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="offerTitle" id="offerTitle" maxlength="70" class="form-control yellow" placeholder="Offer title" value="" />


        <input type="submit" id="addOffer" name="addOffer" class="btn button-black" value="Add Offer" />
     </form> 


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#offersForm').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var offerTitle = $('#offerTitle').val();

        $(".error").removeClass('error');

        if (offerTitle.length < 1) {
            $('#offerTitle').addClass('error');
            return false;
        }

        return true

    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: this code will not work. If you can use https://jqueryvalidation.org/ this plugin that will fix the issue. Otherwise just use normal button and when the button click check your field empty and if not sumbit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check man I have fixed your code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#addOffer').click(function() {
        
        var offerTitle = $('#offerTitle').val();

        $(".error").removeClass('error');

        if (offerTitle.length < 1) {
            $('#offerTitle').addClass('error');
            return false;
        }
      $('#offersForm').submit();
        return true

    });
  });
```

```css
.error{
    border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="offersForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="offerTitle" id="offerTitle" maxlength="70" class="form-control yellow" placeholder="Offer title" value="" />


        <input type="button" id="addOffer" name="addOffer" class="btn button-black" value="Add Offer" />
     </form>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks - so in short, don't use the jquery .submit method for the form, use the on click method on the submit button, which is not a form submit button! Works great now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#addOffer').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var offerTitle = $('#offerTitle').val();

        $(".error").removeClass('error');

        if (offerTitle.length < 1) {
            $('#offerTitle').addClass('error');
            return false;
        }
      $('#offersForm').submit();
        return true

    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="offersForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="offerTitle" id="offerTitle" maxlength="70" class="form-control yellow" placeholder="Offer title" value="" />


        <input type="button" id="addOffer" name="addOffer" class="btn button-black" value="Add Offer" />
     </form>
```